# How to fix sonar issues for Reduce the number of conditional operators (5) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3) in java

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
ObjectTest systemError = (ObjectTest ) o;
//New Code 
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp1, systemError.exp1);
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp2, systemError.exp2)  ;
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp3, systemError.exp3);
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp4, systemError.exp4);
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp5, systemError.exp5) ;
result &= Objects.equals(this.exp6, systemError.exp6);
return result;
//Old Code
return Objects.equals(this.exp, systemError.exp) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp1, systemError.exp1) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp2, systemError.exp2) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp3, systemError.exp3) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp4, systemError.exp4) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp5, systemError.exp5) &&
Objects.equals(this.exp6, systemError.exp6);
```

Does the New code is the solution for Old code ?Can any one shed some confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `a &= b` is same as `a = a & b` which will have the same result as `a = a && b` for practical purposes (except for performance as irrespective of the value of `a`, `b` will also be evaluated in case of `a & b` while in case of `a && b`, `b` is not processed if `a` is `false`)

On this basis, your new code can be indeed the solution for the old code provided you start your new code with `result = Objects.equals(this.exp, systemError.exp);` and end it with `return result;`

Feel free to let me know if you still have any problem understanding it and I will try to elaborate my explanation a bit further.

Comment: Thanks I will accept the answer and explanation given by you.